# What must I do run to Python code with imported modules in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense, python-import

Example for the question.

File Structure

```
foo_folder
    |
    bar_module.py
    |     |___foo_func
    |     |____init___
    python application folder
          |___python_solution.sln, .proj ...
          |___python_application.py
```

bar_module.py:

```
def foo_func():
    return 3.14
```

python_application.py

```
from clients.reddit import foo_module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo_module.foo_func())
```

I have a solution with a project and one .py file in it. The file in that project imports a module outside the project. Now in PowerShell this works.  But in Visual Studio it doesn't. These are the issues:

1. I can't run this code from Visual Studio as I get an import error.
2. Intellisense doesn't work. When I'm working in python_application.py there is no `intellisense` for `bar_module`.

Now I realize I could add `bar_module.py` to the project, but that makes a local copy which I don't want. What do I need to change so I can run this code from Visual Studio and get Intellisense to work?